# Is there a word/phrase for "reliable in the long run"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Was wondering if a word or phrase that would fit in the following context:

> Global warming is an increasing threat to us today and forest conservation is the ***reliable in the long run*** way to combat it.

Comment: If you hyphenated, you could get away with it in very informal contexts. Better to use it predicatively.

Comment: Sure, "longterm"--"Global warming is an increasing threat to us today and forest conservation is a longterm way to combat it." "reliable" seems misplaced here, but you could also say "Global warming is an increasing threat to us today and forest conservation is a reliable way to combat it long term."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider *[strategic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/strategic)*

> Relating to the identification of long-term or overall aims and interests and the means of achieving them:
>
> *the company should take strategic actions to cope with fundamental changes in the environment*
>
> *strategic planning for the organization is the responsibility of top management*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

*Strategic* has the advantage of emphasizing long-term, as opposed to *tactical* which concentrates on smaller, short-term objectives or consequences.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for [*slow but sure* (The Free Dictionary)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/slow+but+sure).

> Global warming is an increasing threat to us today and forest conservation is the *slow but sure* way to combat it.

Answer (score 1):

Just, for what it is worth, why not call it the ***enduring solution***?

Comment: You have the best answers and I like them a lot. But I see your answers in the LQ queue way too often. Now this.

Answer (score 0):

By using the word [eventual](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eventual), you imply that the solution isn't immediate. I think it would then sound better with a single word noun like solution instead of "way to combat it".

> Global warming is an increasing threat to us today, and forest conservation is the  *eventual* solution.

Answer (score 0):

*Global warming is an increasing threat to us today and forest conservation is the "**slow is smooth, smooth is fast**" way to combat it.*

> *The "slow is smooth, smooth is fast" saying has its origins in the military. With that context the meaning is fairly obvious: moving fast, or rushing it, is reckless and will likely get you killed. If you move slowly, carefully and deliberate however, you are really moving as fast as you can without needlessly increasing the risk on your life.*
>
> [Answers](http://www.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_interpert_the_quote_Slow_is_smooth_Smooth_is_fast)